# What are the criteria for quality standards? Or... How do I get Super User to accept my question?

Tags: support, questions, low-quality

It seems a rather silly question to ask, but I'm attempting to ask a question on the location of wallpaper files on Windows XP. As always, I've explicitly stated my OS, very specifically spelled out my problem, and have avoided most of the pitfalls I expect a bad question to have.

Its a clear, non argumentative question which has an objective simple answer. It gets rejected for "It does not meet our quality standards. "

I quote the question below (**and no, please do not answer it here** - I don't want to sneak in my question by stealth. I want to know where I am going wrong as to make it a better question) and wonder... why is it failing the quality standards, and how can I make it better.

> I run windows XP and I have a image
>   whose original i can't find that got
>   reset as the wallpaper.I have backups
>   of the system itself - so if i knew
>   where to look, i could find a copy.
>
> I have some idea of the original
>   filename (searching now), and i recall
>   it saves it as a bitmap, but an exact
>   location would be helpful

I tried "where does windows store its wallpaper" and "Location windows stores its wallpaper" as title

Comment: Looks like you've passed the test: http://superuser.com/questions/304801/location-of-current-windows-wallpaper

Comment: added a third para to get around the lameness filter, then deleted it ;p

Comment: @Sathya What's the point in improving the quote if the entire topic might be related to possibly poor grammar and punctuation?

Comment: @Daniel - *that* was accidental - thanks to [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2209/se-editor-toolkit) script that I use for editing

Comment: hmm.. does that work while posting as well? ;p

Comment: @JourneyMan no.. but you can always post & edit ;)

Answer (score 9):

Should you come across this warning, please re-read your question and check for basic spelling errors. This fix alone should cover the quality standards trigger.

A few things to look at from your example:

- the lowercase "i" in use as the pronoun "I" should be uppercase
- there should be a space between the period/fullstop (.) and the start of the next sentence

Comment: Fixed both, still getting the warning.

Comment: More information on more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards @jou

Answer (score 7):

I've often edited your posts - most of them follow the same, um, style

- Lack of proper casing ( refer: title before my edit)
- Some punctuation marks are missing

Have a look at the posts I've edited, you'll see the pattern. Fixing these ought to bump up the quality indicator